# ActiveDirectoryServices.AccountManagment - LastPasswordSet - UTC time

Tags: c#, datetime, active-directory, utc

I was originally using `ActiveDirectoryServices`, but switch to `ActiveDirectoryServices.AccountManagment` base on the suggestion of other members here. It's much easier to work with, but it is presenting one challenge. When returning the `LastPasswordSet`, it is in UTC instead of the local time. How can I get around this?

Thanks,

Jason

```
public UserPrincipal GetUser(string sUserName)
{
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal =
       UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
    if (oUserPrincipal != null)
    {
        BuildUser(oUserPrincipal);
    }
    return oUserPrincipal;
}

private void BuildUser(UserPrincipal user)
{
    //Populate the user with items available in the UserPrincipal object
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.LastPasswordSet.HasValue)
        this.PasswordLastSet = (DateTime)user.LastPasswordSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime has a static method `SpecifyKind`. It specifies whether a DateTime object represents a local time, a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or is not specified as either local time or UTC. [Here is the link to original Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx).

The Instance Method `ToLocalTime` converts the value of the current DateTime object to local time.

The Instance Method `ToUniversalTime` converts the value of the current DateTime object to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Answer (score 3):

Change the

```
(DateTime)user.LastPasswordSet;
```

to

```
user.LastPasswordSet.Value.ToLocalTime();
```